# How to PASS ON proximity change event

Tags: android, event-listener, proximity

I've a broadcast receiver for phone state changes, and when phone state is "OFFHOOK", I register an eventlistener for proximity sensor. When the proximity changes , I do something(I do the registering and the 'something' in a service ,for that matters). So far everything works as expected. The problem is that screen is not getting locked when the proximity value is 'CLOSE'. I think this is because my listener is catching the proximity change event and so the phone's default application ain't getting the event. Is there a way to pass on the event, like 'return false' in onClickListener() of buttons.

edit:

**Codes**

In the oncreate of the service

```
        myProximitySensor = mySensorManager
                .getDefaultSensor(Sensor.TYPE_PROXIMITY);
        mySensorManager.registerListener(this, myProximitySensor,
            SensorManager.SENSOR_DELAY_NORMAL);
```

I implemented the SensorEventListener, and in it's onSensorChanged() method:

```
AudioManager audioManager = (AudioManager) getSystemService(Context.AUDIO_SERVICE);
    audioManager.setSpeakerphoneOn(true);
```

Comment: can you please post some code?

Comment: Contrary to what you assume the proximity event does NOT get consumed. All the eventListeners registered will receive the event. So there is no need to "pass-on". Maybe the app/service is holding onto a wakelock that keeps/pokes the device screen ON. Hmmm?...

Comment: @TheCodeArtist Thanks for the reply.Do you think calling a service from the broadcast receiver is causing the problem?

Comment: Check http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/PowerManager.html for more info. Is there any `wakelock` being acquired/released in broadcast-receiver or the service in question?...

Comment: no wakelock is aquired or released.The problem is spotted ,thanks to you.I am using AudioManager to enable speakerphone when phone is held away from user.When I commented the AudioManager code, the screen locking is working.Is there a way I can turn on the speakerphone without this 'screen not locking' effect ?

Comment: to be precise "audioManager.setSpeakerphoneOn(state);" code is causing the trouble.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to lock your screen when proximity listener change
you can have an instance of **PowerManager.WakeLock**
and call acquire on it to lock sceen
and then call release to unlock the screen again

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please review [How do I write a good answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7656/how-do-i-write-a-good-answer-to-a-question).